# Talmud passage relevant to #metoo

Tags: talmud-gemara, women, sexuality, tznius-modesty, violence

At the Seder table, my sister told me about a passage in the Talmud advocating that women go to the toilet together, lest they be raped. I was wondering if anyone had the exact location?

Comment: razumny, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you'll look around to find other information of interest (perhaps starting with some of our [tag:yichud-seclusion] material), and continue asking and answering.

Answer (score 8):

The reference is to [Sanhedrin 19a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.19a.12?lang=bi) where it is recorded that R Yosi enacted in Tzippori that women speak to each other aloud when in the outhouses so men would hear them and know not to come in (which would present a problem of Yichud). This is brought in Shulchan Arukh ([EH 22:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.22.13?lang=bi)) though the Rama notes that in our bathrooms which aren't out in fields, this enactment doesn't apply.

Comment: Note that the Talmud is talking about preventing *mistakes*, not a diabolical predator. So whoever read that as "lest they be raped" was mistaken.

Comment: @shalom well that's Rashi's read at least. One could read it that the enactment prevented problems by forcing people to speak which prevented cross-dressing men (with lower voices) from entering, or some other variation. When the Talmud says it's a problem of Yichud, it could be speaking politely

Comment: Note that the enactment recorded immediately previously in the Talmud   and immediately afterward in the Shulchan Aruch does [also] address risk of sexual abuse.

Comment: I always wondered if the other story was euphemistic, or if their world was just less sick -- "they bad guys found the child alone in the street so they kidnapped the child and then raped ... the child's mother."